# React reusable component library styles not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass

hey people I need help with the following:

- am creating React UI component library
- I am using webpack and dev build works great, scss files are loaded and components are displayed correctly
- on production build, JS bundle is created as well as CSS (I use SCSS) bundle
- BUT when I install the library in another React project and import the component, CSS is not loaded (cmp is not styled), JS works fine and the component is rendered yet styles are not loaded...

**EDIT**
Apparently this approach requires manual loading of CSS in parent app project. Which I want to avoid. Is there alternative way which can provide scenario in which styles will be resolved on the level on component without need for manual loading?

Here is my production webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {

  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {

    filename: 'bundle.js',

    path: path.join(__dirname, '../lib'),

    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',

  },

  module: {

    rules: [

      {

        test: /\.css$/,

        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({

          fallback: 'style-loader',

          use: ['css-loader']

        })

      },

      {

        test: /\.scss$/,

        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({

          fallback: 'style-loader',

          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']

        })

      },

      {

        test: /\.js$/,

        exclude: /node_modules/,

        loader: "babel-loader"

      },

      {

        test: /\.svg/,

        use: {

          loader: 'svg-url-loader',

          options: {}

        }

      }

    ]

  },

  externals: {

    'react': 'commonjs react',

    'react-dom': 'commonjs react-dom',

  },

  resolve: {

    modules: [

      path.resolve('./src'),

      path.resolve('./node_modules')

    ]

  },

  plugins: [

    new ExtractTextPlugin({

      filename: 'ui-library.css'

    })

  ]

};
```

Comment: I see you are using `ExtractTextPlugin`. This plugin will extract the css from bundle to separate file. In that case you might have to load that css file separately if you want style to work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a way to handle this without manual loading of CSS?

Comment: You could use a CSS in JS framework like `styled-components`

Comment: That is also a legit info, but we considered it and decided not to use it. Now I am thinking that it is possibly the only option which does not require manual CSS imports in parent app. For example, Material UI is using styled-components and achieve just that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply not use `ExtractTextPlugin`.

The whole purpose of Webpack is to group assets not based on file type but by a component perspective.

So, if you remove `ExtractTextPlugin`, your CSS will be included in your .js bundle.

Comment: This is good enough solution for now. Next best thing would be code splitting on the level of a component so that we end up with a separate bundle for each component. Do you have any pointers where I can look about how to achieve that? Thanks for the info I will mark answer as accepted. If you know the code splitting part please update the answer if possible :)

Comment: You can do that easily with Webpack by having multiple entries ... Each entry become it's own bundle (depending on your config). 

Maybe you can post another question with your webpack config file and your project tree so that I can take a look ?

Comment: Answered there :-)